# How to get SKProduct local price in US Dollar?

Tags: objective-c, localization, in-app-purchase, skproduct

I need to convert SKProduct local price to US Dollar. That means, SKProduct give me local based currency. But i need to show US Dollar rate in every country.

Comment: do you tried any libraries for this ?

Comment: NO. Have you any library?

Comment: try this https://github.com/nunosans/currency

Comment: did u solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try these libraries [DDUnitConverter](https://github.com/davedelong/DDUnitConverter) and  [MGCurrencyExchanger](https://github.com/GenralDesigns/MGCurrencyExchanger)  or  try this code

```
SKProduct *product = [self.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[formatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
currencyString = [formatter stringFromNumber:product.price];`
```

Comment: @DzungPV i thought setLocale will do that

Comment: API from Apple always return local price (IP location), you must fixed the USD price or convert it with exchange rate.