# InApp Purchase product price

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm trying read price of a product in InApp purchase. I want price in US Dollar but I receive in local currency INR. I wanted to show price in US dollar in every countries.

```
let product = SKProduct()// my product object
 let price = product.price // receives always in INR
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658966/how-to-get-skproduct-local-price-in-us-dollar?rq=1 this may help

Answer (score 0):

App purchase price is depend which Locale you are login from your App Store account. you can check locale

```
    let locale = Locale.current
    let currencySymbol = locale.currencySymbol!
    let currencyCode = locale.currencyCode!
```

Product Price you can check as this delegate method

```
//SKProductsRequestDelegate

 public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("Loaded list of products...")
    let products = response.products
    productsRequestCompletionHandler?(true, products)
    clearRequestAndHandler()

    for p in products {
        print("Found product: \(p.productIdentifier) \(p.localizedTitle) \(p.price.floatValue)")
        print("product price --%@",p.price)
    }


}
```

Comment: how do I get price amount always in USD even if Im accessing from another country?

Comment: @user6788419 App Store manage its depends which country you are login. Check your product price and current Locale for above code

Comment: I think my requirement is not possible

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproduct/1506094-price) you could format the price using a NumberFormmatter where you can also specify your currency.

Please note that you should always use the users locale to format the price provided by SKProduct. You should not format the the price to another currency because SKProduct always return a localized price bound to the current locale. (e. g. French Euro price for french App Store)

Nevertheless here is an example on how you would format the price with only changing the currency symbol:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
numberFormatter.currencyCode = "USD"
let priceInUSD = numberFormatter.string(from: product.price)
```

Comment: I have tried this already. It only changes the symbol of currency.. Nothing happens in amount related with currency exchange rate.

Comment: There is no in-built library to convert the price using Apple's current pricing-matrix... And since SKProduct always returns a localized price you should not try to convert it to another currency... Always present the currency fitting the user's locale.

Comment: Thanks I will do that